# show user's details from table on aspx when logged in

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I posted a similar question previously but quickly deleted it as the question had a number of errors and was not clear for readers.

I am creating a log in for a patient and when logged in (from the log in page login.aspx) I want them to be redirected to a page (in this case user.aspx) when the log in is authenticated and show their details from a table.

So far I can just get a label to provide user logged in correct or user log in incorrect.

I have a patient table as follows  - this is all dummy data and made up user/accounts:

[image: patient table]

This is the code behind file, have I set a session correctly? and how when the user is authenticated can they be redirected to user.aspx with their corresponding details from a table (for instance their user details)

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Pages_Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
        Dim patientNo As String
        Dim password As String
        Dim bAuthethicated As Boolean
        patientNo = txtuser.Text
        password = txtpassword.Text
        bAuthethicated = CheckUser(patientNo, password)

        If bAuthethicated Then
            lblresult.Text() = "correct"
        Else
            lblresult.Text() = "Incorrect Student Number and/or Password"
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function CheckUser(patientNo As String, password As String) As Integer
        Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT * FROM Patient  Where Username=@PATIENTNO AND Password=@PASSWORD"
        Dim found = 0
        Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Laura\Final_proj\App_Data\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
            Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PATIENTNO", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = patientNo
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = password
            conn.Open()

            Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
                found = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
            End While

            reader.Close()
        End Using
        Return (found)
    End Function
End Class
```

I hope someone can help. If I can provide any more information or direction on the question please let me know.

Comment: I hope the image of your data table is dummy data, otherwise I would recommend you remove it as it contains email addresses and passwords...

Comment: its all dummy data - these are all false accounts

Comment: Alright, just making sure :)

Comment: I added this to the question - thank you for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than showing the user that they have successfully logged in, just add the following line of code to redirect them to the user.aspx page:

```
Response.Redirect("user.aspx", True)
```

On the user page, you need to check if the Session("PatientId") is empty, if so, then redirect back the login page. If it does have a value, ensure it is a number and then use it to load up the patient details with another DB call.

Also another tip, I noticed your passwords are in plain text. I would highly recommend that you one-way hash them using a simple function for additional security. You can then use the same function to hash the password used on the login page to compare against the database value.

Comment: Aki - thank you very much for your answer -  from the code I have provided `While reader.Read()
            Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
            found = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId"))
        End While` does this correctly start a session - also in the user.aspx page how do I show them their unique information from say the user table once they have logged in - I will place a grid but unsure how when they are logged in and redirected to user.aspx they can view their unique data

Comment: p.s the redirect works - just want to get the user.aspx page to display the logged in user's details

Comment: Now that the PatientID is securely stored in the session, you can reuse it on the user.aspx page. Create another function like your CheckUser function that SELECT's the patient data with the WHERE clause set to PatientID=@patientId. The parameter value can then be set using the Session("PatientID"). The function can then return the patient data in whatever format you wish, or used to fill a grid/variable/class properties.

Comment: Aki I'm just thinking... Have I called the session correctly - should I have.     ' Protected Sub Login1_LoggingIn(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs) 
Handles Login1.LoggingIn
 Session("StudID") = Login1.UserName.ToString() ' somewhere?

Comment: As I can't see your application fully, it's hard to tell how exactly it is working and what your goals are. From the initial code your provided in your question, it looks like you just needed the PatientID once authenticated. This is fine, but if you wanted to, you could also store the UserName in the session too if you felt it is required. You can do this right under the Session("PatientId") = CInt(reader.Item("PatientId")), e.g. Session("UserName") = CInt(reader.Item("UserName")). I haven't used the login control before, but don't think you need to worry about Login1_LoggingIn function.

Comment: I'm not actually using the login control from toolbox I'm just using two text boxes and a button or should I be using the login control for a session to work?

Comment: No you don't need it for sessions to work. As soon as you set a value to a session variable, it should remain for the remainder of the session. If you are trying to call the session from another page and it is empty, then you may have another issue.

Comment: Ali thank you for all of your responses- how would.I find out if it is empty? Is there anyway to instant talk on this